# Box around a formula with hf-tikz generates another box

Tags: equations, box, hf-tikz

I tried to surround the next formula with hf-tikz

```
\begin{align}
    \tikzmarkin{ceigengo}(10.8,-1.8)(0,0.7)
      \qty(\frac{J'_m(\eta_1 a)}{\eta_1 a J_m(\eta_1 a)}+\frac{K'_m(\eta_2 a)}{\eta_2 a J_m(\eta_1 a)})\qty(\frac{n_1^2J'_m(\eta_1 a)}{\eta_1 a J_m(\eta_1 a)}+\frac{n_2^2K'_m(\eta_2 a)}{\eta_2 a J_m(\eta_1 a)}) \nonumber\\
=m^2\qty(\frac{\beta}{k_0})^2\qty(\qty(\frac{1}{\eta_1 a})^2+\qty(\frac{1}{\eta_2 a})^2)^2
    \tikzmarkin{ceigengo} 
\end{align}
```

And this was my result

[image: A rare little box]

The little box inside the bigger box and near the numbering is the thing that i want doesn't appear, this problem only occurs me with this big formula. What i should do?

Comment: Welcome! Please post a minimal and complete example of the code that generates this. It is easier for others to copy and paste the entire code you provide to debug it than just code snippets.

Comment: Welcome! Shouldn't the second one be a `\tikzmarkend{ceigengo}` or so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to end the box with `\tikzmarkend`. In your example the fill is only roughly what it should be because you have the large dimensions in `(10.8,-1.8)(0,0.7)`. The second box comes from the second `\tikzmarkin`. If you use `\tikzmarkend` instead, you do no longer need add the large dimensions by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \tikzmarkin{ceigengo}(0.1,-0.7)(-0.1,0.7)
      \qty(\frac{J'_m(\eta_1 a)}{\eta_1 a J_m(\eta_1 a)}+\frac{K'_m(\eta_2 a)}{\eta_2 a J_m(\eta_1 a)})\qty(\frac{n_1^2J'_m(\eta_1 a)}{\eta_1 a J_m(\eta_1 a)}+\frac{n_2^2K'_m(\eta_2 a)}{\eta_2 a J_m(\eta_1 a)}) \nonumber\\
=m^2\qty(\frac{\beta}{k_0})^2\qty(\qty(\frac{1}{\eta_1 a})^2+\qty(\frac{1}{\eta_2 a})^2)^2
    \tikzmarkend{ceigengo} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me mention that I would not use the `physics` package.

Note also that you could combine `tcolorbox` with `empheq` to get similar results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\definecolor{fancybrown}{RGB}{255,216,197}%  copied from
\definecolor{fancyviolet}{RGB}{197,122,197}% hf-tikz
\tcbset{highlight math style={colback=fancybrown,colframe=fancyviolet}}
\mleftright
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align}
  \left(\frac{J'_m(\eta_1 a)}{\eta_1 a J_m(\eta_1 a)}
  +\frac{K'_m(\eta_2 a)}{\eta_2 a J_m(\eta_1 a)}\right)
  \left(\frac{n_1^2J'_m(\eta_1 a)}{\eta_1 a J_m(\eta_1 a)}
  +\frac{n_2^2K'_m(\eta_2 a)}{\eta_2 a J_m(\eta_1 a)}\right) 
  \nonumber\\
 =m^2\left(\frac{\beta}{k_0}\right)^2\left(\left(\frac{1}{\eta_1 a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\eta_2 a}\right)^2\right)^2
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]